# onkeyup prevents f:ajax in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm encountering a strange issue where an onkeyup event prevents an ajax event from being executed in IE.

```
<p:inputText id="mileage" value="#{quoteInput.mileage}" styleClass="imedium required" required="true" disabled="#{quoteRequest.quoteDisabled}" onkeyup="typePosReal(this)">
                <f:ajax execute="@this" render="@this"/>
                <mw:convertDouble locale="#{ws.numberFormatLocale}" minFractionDigits="2" maxFractionDigits="2"/>
            </p:inputText>
```

In the above snippet, removing the `onkeyup="typePosReal(this)"` fragment makes things work again, but then I'm losing my javascript functionality.

This is with JSF2.0 and PrimeFaces4.
Any ideas what to do here?

**EDIT**

The JS function modifies the value of the input text (sometimes)

```
function typePosReal(field) {
    field.value = (decimalsep == ',') ? 
         field.value.replace(/\./, ',') : field.value.replace(/\,/, '.'); 
    field.value = field.value.replace(/[^0-9\.,]+/g, ''); return true;
}
```

Commenting out the lines the modify the field's value makes the ajax work correctly in IE...

Comment: It may have caused a JS error. Did you check the JS console for errors?

Comment: Yes, no errors, and no subsequent xml/http request

Comment: Okay. What exactly is the `typePosReal()` function doing? Does it do something with `event`?

Comment: function typePosReal(field) {
 field.value = (decimalsep == ',') ? field.value.replace(/\./, ',') : field.value.replace(/\,/, '.');
 field.value = field.value.replace(/[^0-9\.,]+/g, '');
 return true;
}

Comment: Meanwhile I found that if I edit typePosReal() to only do "return true", the ajax submit is performed. Since the lines are not really causing errors, I'm curious why changing the field value prevents the f:ajax to fire.

Comment: Which IE version? As to the function's job, why don't you just perform conversion in a normal converter?

Comment: That comma vs dot thing is an annoyance on Belgian keyboard. Dot is on the numpad, but we use comma as decimal separator, so we do replace while the user types to show its effect. Happens in IE10 and IE11 afaik.